# How to compress multiple .jpg files simultaneously, using "Send to"?

Tags: windows, microsoft-outlook, compression, jpeg

If I have say 20 photographs saved as .jpgs, each of size 3MB, and I need to send them as attachments to an email, it can be useful to compress them each to say no more than a few hundred kB before sending. This may be done for individual files by means of the following procedure:

- select, right-click, then choose `Send to... | Mail recipient`, then `Medium: 1024 x 768`
- click on `Attach`.

This makes Microsoft Outlook do its business, and you can then

- select a .jpg file in that program's `Compose: Emailing` window and click to open it,
- choose `Save to Disk`, and then
- save it where you want, and you will find that you are saving a compressed file

Note that this does not require using MS Outlook as your mail client, which practically nobody who has had experience with a proper mail client would wish to do.

My question is how can we amend the above procedure to compress several files at once. At the moment when I try to do this by selecting multiple files in the `Compose: Emailing` window I can get all the way to saving, but the files are saved uncompressed.

I am using Windows 7 Pro with Service Pack 1.

Comment: jpg's are already compressed, re-compressing them will gain little.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that it isn't your e-mail application that is accomplishing this - it is your operating system. Likewise, it's not really *compressing* the files per se - you're just resizing them dramatically, which reduces the file size. It is possible to use the same steps you were, only you can first select multiple pictures and then use the `Send to` > `Mail recipient` step to bulk resize them to whatever size you've selected - for example, if you select `Medium: 1024 x 768`, the `1024 x 768` is what Windows considers a standard landscape picture in Medium size, but the actual numbers for a Medium sized portrait picture will be different (though the option will still say `1024 x 768`). From there you could just save them from your mail app as you normally would.

On a side note, if you wanted to send multiple files into one compressed folder, you could use the following steps:

> - Put all of the pictures in a folder
> - Right-click the folder
> - Highlight `Send to`
> - Select `Compressed (zipped) folder`
> - Name the compressed folder what you want
> - Right-click the compressed folder
> - Send to mail recipient as you were previously

This won't reduce the size nearly as much for what you are trying to compress, but it can be an option with other file types.

Comment: Many thanks for this. You are right - I meant resize rather than compress. I tried your first method and noticed that for some reason the mail client being opened is Thunderbird, which still won't allow multiple images to be saved. (Neither Outlook nor Thunderbird are my normal mail client, which is Turnpike.) Your second method worked fine but compressed only by 2%,

Comment: What is your default mail program set to? You should be able to change it to whatever you need it to be. If you're looking to bulk resize images I would probably recommend that you look into an app that does that as opposed to the `Send to` method.